# CRUD operations parse.com and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I am trying to create an angular web app with basic CRUD operations and stored in https://parse.com/ , i am looking for documentation about this topic but   didn't found anything yet. Anyone have worked with this before who can guide me.

Comment: Both the parse javascript SDK and REST service are well documented. Angular doesn't care where the data comes from and there are available modules for angular parse ... look a little harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, main problem when integrating Parse and angular is handling callbacks/promises from Parse.  If you haven't run into the case where you need to manually call `$scope.$apply` in Angular, I'm sure you will soon.  Angular's two way binding relies on something that is called Digest Loops.

Angular knows how to handle stuff that comes from angular services, directives, etc. but will you will run into many difficulties when trying to combine calls to other frameworks. This can be solved in many ways.

In regards to the framework at hand, Parse, you have a few options:

One, which I use most of the time, is wrapping calls to parse's javascript sdk with an angular promise, using the $q service.  So this would go something like:

```
angular
  .module('YourApp')
  .service('TestObject', function($q) {
    var self = this; 
    self.get = function(id) {

        var d = $q.defer(),
            TestObject = Parse.Object.extend('TestObject'),
            q = new Parse.Query(TestObject);

        q.get(id)
        .then(function(testObject) {
            d.resolve(testObject)
        }, function(err) {
            d.reject(err)
        }) 


        return d.promise;
    }
 });
```

Angular and Parse promises are very similar in syntax, but angular has more stuff going on because it needs to handle $scopes and such.  So you have to wrap the Parse promise with an angular one.

Second option, I haven't used, but looks interesting, which basically does the same as I explained above is: https://github.com/brandid/parse-angular-patch . If you give it a shot, let me know.